# Segregate Repeat Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This probably has been asked before...

I have long files of recorded values such as Time, Temperature, etc. based on a certain step the input function is in. A 'Step' column records the current step, in this case 1 to 20 steps. The steps can repeat such as below (small portion of data):

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [{'Date': '1-10-19', 'Read': 1.1, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '2-10-19', 'Read': 1.11, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '3-10-19', 'Read': 10.1, 'Step': 2},
            {'Date': '4-10-19', 'Read': 10.11, 'Step': 2},
            {'Date': '5-10-19', 'Read': 1.2, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '6-10-19', 'Read': 1.21, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '7-10-19', 'Read': 10.2, 'Step': 2},
            {'Date': '8-10-19', 'Read': 10.21, 'Step': 2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

```
      Date   Read  Step
0  1-10-19   1.10     1
1  2-10-19   1.11     1
2  3-10-19  10.10     2
3  4-10-19  10.11     2
4  5-10-19   1.20     1
5  6-10-19   1.21     1
6  7-10-19  10.20     2
7  8-10-19  10.21     2
```

I need to keep track of the Step sequence groups over time such as below:

```
      Date   Read  Step   Step_New
0  1-10-19   1.10     1   1.1
1  2-10-19   1.11     1   1.1
2  3-10-19  10.10     2   2.1
3  4-10-19  10.11     2   2.1
4  5-10-19   1.20     1   1.2
5  6-10-19   1.21     1   1.2
6  7-10-19  10.20     2   2.2
7  8-10-19  10.21     2   2.2
```

How should I add this new column? Eventually I'll `groupby` this column to perform some statistics on the new individual steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the help of a memory to remember on which step for each particular step you are. 
With the use of apply you can then create a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = [{'Date': '1-10-19', 'Read': 1.1, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '2-10-19', 'Read': 1.11, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '3-10-19', 'Read': 10.1, 'Step': 2},
            {'Date': '4-10-19', 'Read': 10.11, 'Step': 2},
            {'Date': '5-10-19', 'Read': 1.2, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '6-10-19', 'Read': 1.21, 'Step': 1},
            {'Date': '7-10-19', 'Read': 10.2, 'Step': 2},
            {'Date': '8-10-19', 'Read': 10.21, 'Step': 2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

step_memory = {}
last_step = -1

def calculate_new_step(row):
    global last_step
    step = row['Step']
    output = str(step) + "."
    if step == last_step:
        output += str(step_memory[step])
    else:
        last_step = step
        step_memory[step] = step_memory.get(step, 0) + 1
        output += str(step_memory[step])
    return float(output) #if you want it as a String delete float

df['Step_New'] = df.apply(calculate_new_step, axis=1)
print(df)
```

## Output:

```
      Date   Read  Step  Step_New
0  1-10-19   1.10     1       1.1
1  2-10-19   1.11     1       1.1
2  3-10-19  10.10     2       2.1
3  4-10-19  10.11     2       2.1
4  5-10-19   1.20     1       1.2
5  6-10-19   1.21     1       1.2
6  7-10-19  10.20     2       2.2
7  8-10-19  10.21     2       2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative tracking the decimal step for each Step group:

```
       Date    Read  Step
0   1-10-19    1.10     1
1   2-10-19    1.11     1
2   3-10-19   10.10     2
3   4-10-19   10.11     2
4   5-10-19    1.20     1
5   6-10-19    1.21     1
6   7-10-19   10.20     2
7   8-10-19   10.21     2
8   8-10-19  100.10     3
9   8-10-19  100.11     3
10  6-10-19    1.22     1
11  6-10-19    1.31     1

df["Step_New"] = df.Step + df.groupby('Step')['Read'].apply(lambda x: round(x - x.astype(int), 1))
```

Output:

```
       Date    Read  Step  Step_New
0   1-10-19    1.10     1       1.1
1   2-10-19    1.11     1       1.1
2   3-10-19   10.10     2       2.1
3   4-10-19   10.11     2       2.1
4   5-10-19    1.20     1       1.2
5   6-10-19    1.21     1       1.2
6   7-10-19   10.20     2       2.2
7   8-10-19   10.21     2       2.2
8   8-10-19  100.10     3       3.1
9   8-10-19  100.11     3       3.1
10  6-10-19    1.22     1       1.2
11  6-10-19    1.31     1       1.3
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work as soon as you add another row of step 1 or step 3.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Added both, seems to be holding.

Comment: use the test data from my post. 
Also in your post row 10 has step_new 1.2 and row 11 1.3 but both should have Step_new 1.3

Comment: I guess we understood different things, from what I got row 10 with Read of 1.22 should still have a Step_New of 1.2, not 1.3. Anyhow...